# Unable to install parse.com command line tool on Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: macos, parse-platform, osx-yosemite

Running the command

```html
curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash
```

does not install the tool

I was able to install it easily on my other computer running 10.9.2

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Nothing happens, when I run it without the -s it seems to show that nothing is even downloading

Comment: What if you just run the curl command without piping to the sudo shell?

Comment: If i run it without -s I get curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate. If it run it without -s and with -k I get #!/bin/bash

TMP_FILE=/tmp/parse.tmp
if [ -e /tmp/parse.tmp ]; then
  echo "Cleaning up from previous install failure"
  rm -f /tmp/parse.tmp
fi
echo "Fetching latest version ..."
curl --progress-bar https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/parse -o /tmp/parse.tmp
if [ ! -d /usr/local/bin ]; then
  echo "Making /usr/local/bin"
  mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
fi
echo "Installing ..."
mv /tmp/parse.tmp /usr/local/bin/parse
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/parse

Comment: Any update on this. I am facing the same behaviour on Fedora 19 x86_64

Comment: Did you got a fix means post it that others cam make use of it @JaredRosen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STEP : 1**
Make a copy of this

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP_FILE=/tmp/parse.tmp
if [ -e /tmp/parse.tmp ]; then
echo "Cleaning up from previous install failure"
rm -f /tmp/parse.tmp
fi
echo "Fetching latest version ..."
curl --progress-bar https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/parse -o /tmp/parse.tmp
if [ ! -d /usr/local/bin ]; then
echo "Making /usr/local/bin"
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
fi
echo "Installing ..."
mv /tmp/parse.tmp /usr/local/bin/parse
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/parse `
```

to a file named **install.sh** and run it in your terminal as `bash install.sh`. This will install you parse in your Terminal.

**STEP :2**
Download the Gist from this [link](https://gist.github.com/asmallteapot/efc10aca6aaa5e729735/download#) and run the file named install.sh in your Terminal preceded by bash